# Adding numbers at regular intervals

Tags: excel

Suppose i have to add numbers in the cell B1, F1, J1 giving a gap of 3 cells. Now it should catch the number by itself in column N1, if i enter something in it. Can it be done?

Comment: Your question is vague, and it does not appear to be programming (VBA) related. You will need to add further information, and examples if this to to progress

Comment: ofcourse its not related to VBA, general excel. just like subtotal catches the cells by itself if you add new numbers to the existing range of cells, similarly if the numbers are in different cells but the pattern is similar, then is there a way to add those? B1 has number 4 in it, F1 has 5 , j1 - 6, so the sum comes out to be 15, now if i add 7 in N1 then it should make the sum 22. is that possible?

Comment: In that case you should ask this question at Super User not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(1:1)-2,4) = 0)*(1:1))
```

EDIT

You've asked for clarification, so I'll try.  The first part, `MOD(COLUMN(1:1)-2,4)=0` generates an array of TRUE and FALSES, with a TRUE in every fourth cell in Row 1, starting with the 2nd cell.  So it would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, etc) * (1:1))
```

Since Trues equal 1 and Falses equal 0 when multiplied, you are multiplying every 4th cell by 1.

The Column part returns the column number of every cell in row 1.  Mod returns the remainder when one number is divided by another, so the Mod part yields 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3 etc.  So every 4th one yields a True, as shown above.  That means every 4th number is multiplied by one.  The Sumproduct then adds them together.

There's lots of articles about SumProduct out there.  [Here's one.](http://www.ozgrid.com/News/apr-2005.htm)

Comment: +1 elegantly done Doug. The only part you may want to test (depending on feedback from madyykk) is stopping the addition when there is a gap. ie if N1 is blank and R1 is 8 then should the R value still be added.

Comment: Pls ignore my above comment (other than +1) as I incorrectly saw a pattern being requested when it was simply every fourth cell - as your formula delivers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUM function for individual cells and not just a range of cells.

For example, you could use this formula:

```
=SUM(B1,F1,J1,N1,R1,V1,Z1,AD1,AH1)
```

And keep going as far as you need to go.  If a cell is blank, it will assume that it is 0, so as soon as you enter a value, it will automatically update the cell that contains the formula.

Comment: This does not answer the question which requires a "pattern" test to be met

Comment: Well, this does actually match a pattern, but you have to enter it manually.  Are you asking for something that automatically checks all cells to infinity?

Comment: This is a simple total formula. The question has asked whether it is possible to add every fourth cell if that cell is 1 higher than the initial cell in the pattern

Comment: actually, it doesn't say "if it is 1 higher".  That changes the question significantly.  :)

Comment: "B1 has number 4 in it, F1 has 5 , j1 - 6, so the sum comes out to be 15, now if i add 7 in N1". Looks like 1 higher to me! :)

Comment: It does indeed, but he didn't specify that it MUST be one higher.  :)  In fact, the original questions just says "some numbers" and doesn't mention a pattern at all.  From his comment, you are assuming that he wants to detect a pattern and not just "add the numbers" like he says in his question?  (Great answer by the way, but I'm not sure that is what he is looking for).

Comment: Thanks, but a slight correction on your answer would make this continue for the width of the spreadsheet (which could be quite useful and a good example for others!)

Comment: I didnt put forward an answer - Doug did. I was too busy trying to get to the bottom of the question! :)

Comment: Haha, I'm confusing my people!

Comment: this might not be the appropriate answer, consider this formula - =SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(1:1)-2,4) = 0)*(1:1)) . this does the job. But i am not able to decipher it.